# Expressionengine PHP calling

Tags: php, tags, categories, expressionengine

I wrote the following PHP function to return the current category based on segment 3 URL.

```
<?php
 $this->EE =& get_instance();
 $seg3 = $this->EE->uri->segment(3);
 $categoriess = getCategory($seg3);

function getCategory($string)
   {
     switch ($string)
       {
         case "test1": return '16';
         case "test2": return '52';
         case "test3": return '18';
         case "test4": return '29';
         case "test5": return '37';
       }
     return '11';
   }
 ?>
 <?php echo $categoriess; ?>
```

Well, the function does the job and returns correct number. The problem is then with calling the returned number within the category tag.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel=“news” dynamic=“no” category=”<?php echo $categoriess; ?>” orderby=“entry_date” disable=“member_data|trackbacks” sort=“desc” limit=“5”}
```

Everything looks correct to me but it just doesn’t work…
I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Wtf are those quotes? `“test5”`, `‘37’`? Write like: `case "test5": return 37;`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER if I remove the quotes from the return

Comment: Since what time returning usual integer is supposed to be an error?

Answer (score 1):

**Check your parsing order:** Set "PHP Parsing Stage" to "Input" in the template preferences.

The default setting is "Output", and that works well if you want to get a value *from* an EE shortcode and make it available for PHP as a variable.

But in this case you want to run a function in PHP and then "feed" the return *to* EE.

So in this case EE will take "input" from PHP, and that means the **PHP Parsing Stage** under **Preferences** for **that particular template** (not general preferences or anywhere else) must be set to **Input**.

I see this is an old question now, but I hope someone will have use of this answer anyway. I just wasted a full day trying to do something that would take less than 5 minutes if I'd thought to check the parsing order first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function getCategory($string)
    {
         $data = array(
           "test1" => 16,
           "test2" => 52,
           "test3" => 18,
           "test4" => 29,
           "test5" => 37
         ) ;
         return (isset($data[$string])) ? $data[$string] : 11 ;
     }
   $this->EE =& get_instance();
   $seg3 = $this->EE->uri->segment(3);
   $categoriess = getCategory($seg3);
?>
```

Comment: The same issue.Blank page with number returned.

Comment: And what do you want to display?

Comment: A content of a page. The whole thing is based on if 
category = test1 then display only entries for that category. 
I have an index page that displays main category but if the url is like index/maincateogory/test1 display only entries for the test1 category

Comment: Updated the code, try again. Otherwise, I really cannot see how I can help you.

Comment: Did not help. Thanks Jari anyway.

Comment: No prob. Just search for a mistake. The code, that you have provided is not enough though to find the problem.

Comment: Just a question, why don't you use native category filters of exp:channel:entries?